# Ant Design: Correct type of Menu onClick event parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to use a navigation component from Antd (https://ant.design/components/menu), but it's giving me this error:
`Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

I have tried doing `e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` but then the error shifts to  `e.key`: `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>'`.

Following is my App.tsx:

```
import { AppstoreOutlined, MailOutlined, SettingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';
import { Menu } from 'antd';

const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
  {
    label: 'Navigation One',
    key: 'mail',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
  {
    label: 'Navigation Two',
    key: 'app',
    icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
    disabled: true,
  },
  {
    label: 'Navigation Three - Submenu',
    key: 'SubMenu',
    icon: <SettingOutlined />,
    children: [
      {
        type: 'group',
        label: 'Item 1',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Option 1',
            key: 'setting:1',
          },
          {
            label: 'Option 2',
            key: 'setting:2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'group',
        label: 'Item 2',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Option 3',
            key: 'setting:3',
          },
          {
            label: 'Option 4',
            key: 'setting:4',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: (
      <a href="https://ant.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        Navigation Four - Link
      </a>
    ),
    key: 'alipay',
  },
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('mail');

  const onClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    setCurrent(e.key);
  };

  return <Menu onClick={(onClick)} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
};

export default App;
```

I am new to this and have already spent many hours trying to fix this, any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Error message says of what type is 'e'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type of `e` is the [MenuInfo](https://github.com/react-component/menu/blob/master/src/interface.ts#L93) interface defined in the react-component library (rc-menu). Unfortunately, this type isn't exported. As a workaround, you can use the following code to indirectly reference the MenuInfo interface:

```
const onClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = (e: Parameters<MenuProps['onClick']>[0]) => {
```

The [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type returns an array type containing the parameter types of the specified function, and the `[0]` indexer returns the type of the first (and only) parameter.

Comment: Hey thank you! for the reply, I tried what you suggested but now ```setCurrent(e.key)``` generates the error: ```e is of type 'unknown'```. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm using `typescript@4.9.5` and `antd@5.2.2`, and the code compiles successfully. What version of `typescript` and `antd` are you using? How are you building the app? If you're using Visual Studio Code, does the error show up in the editor? Or is the error only showing up when you actually build the app? In the worst case, you could always change the parameter type to `{ key: string; }` or even `any` to get past this.

Comment: I am using the same version for both. The error was showing up in the editor, and when I was building it. I am not sure how it worked but I just restarted vs code and it's working now! Thank you so much!